# TL071 doesn't work like a generic op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, integrated-circuit, dc, proteus

I am trying to use the TL071 for a project. I run my simulations on Proteus.

After I ran the simulations and verified the circuit behaves as I want, I ordered the parts and put the circuit together.

Later on I realized that the TL071 doesn't work as it worked in the simulation. I checked the simulation and I realized I didn't check the "attach hierarchy module" box which makes the component behave like the specific component, rather than a generic op-amp.

After checking the box I saw that the TL071 behaves exactly like it behaves in the real circuit.

The problem is I can't understand why. I wanted to use a TL071 to make a comparator, which didn't work.

I tried using an LM311, but it didn't work in the simulation either (0 volts as output in every sceneraio.)

As a last resort I wanted to use the TL071 as a simple amplifier.

Even then it did not work as intended.

Below I post the simple amplifier setup. I should get about 12-10 volts output, but instead I get 0 volts.

I tried it in the real circuit and I saw that when I put together the same amplifier with the TL071 I get 0 volts again so the simulation is not the problem.

After unchecking the "attach hierarchy module" option I saw that the op-amp behaves as expected and produces 10.5 volts output. I use the exact supplies in the real circuit. I tried amplifying a sine wave signal it doesn't work either.

[image: circuit]

Below is when simulation running:

[image: Sim running]

Edit2: The whole circuit. This simulation works but in a real circuit I get the result below.

[image: circuit]

edit: I tried the actual circuit with using +12/-12 volt supplies, 0 volt ground and a sinewave as input. VCC is 12V, VEE is -12V, inverting input is connected to the ground and non inverting input is connected to the sinewave. I get this weird wavefrom instead of a square wave as result.

Edit3: In real circuit I realized the op-amp gets very, very hot. I almost burnt my hand.

[image: waveform]

Comment: Can you post with the simulation values?

Comment: I added. Only value is the 0 Volts output though.

Comment: Feedback goes to - input not +

Comment: The problem with swapping of the op-amp input pins was pointed out to you in the second comment to your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571487/tl071-does-not-integrate-my-sine-wave).

Comment: @Transistor yeah and ı tried to make a comparator according to those instructions but it didnt work either.

Comment: OK, but deliberately wiring them incorrectly definitely won't work so why are you still doing it?

Comment: @Transistor wait you lost me, wiring them incorrectly? I tried switching the pins too, still 0V. I built the amplifier to test whether the op-amp works and I still get 0 volts output. The main problem either as a comparator or amplifier I get 0 volts.

Comment: "*Below I post the simple amplifier setup*" Maybe that sentence explains the confusion, since your circuit clearly is not an amplifier.

Comment: "*... inverting input is connected to the ground and non inverting input is connected to the sinewave.*" Please post a schematic so we're clear. You still have your original schematics with feedback connected to the non-inverting input so we can't be sure that you've got it right this time either.

Comment: In simulator I managed to obtain the square wave. I have trouble with the actual circuit now. You might think that I might be connecting something wrong since the simulation works but I keep checking and cant see a difference with the working simulation connections and my real life connections. I post the whole circuit in the edit2 part. I labeled the outputs so it is easier to track.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you don't need to attach hierarchy module. This is used to edit the child sheet to turn the component into a module and attach subcircuits etc. Which can be useful when designing your own component. With nothing on the child sheet, it won't really do much.

Secondly, you have the amplifier incorrectly configured. It looks like you are going for the non-inverting amplifier configuration, but you have the feedback going into the non-inverting terminal, so the behavior will not be as expected. You need to have the input voltage going in to the non inverting input, and the feedback goes to the inverting input.

The reason you are getting 10.5V is because the gain is 1+(R6/R5) = 1+(10k/1k) = 11. With 6V in, your output should be 66V, but because the supply rail only goes up to 12V, it is limited. Looking at the [DATASHEET](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tl071.pdf) for this device, you can see the output voltage swing isn't rail-to-rail. The positive output for a ± 15V supply is typically about 13.5V, so around 10.5V is to be expected.

Comment: I know, but I get 0 Volts both on real life and simulation.

Comment: That's because the simulation is correct; this schematic isn't an amplifier.

Comment: @Tombeki your simulation isn't correct. With the heirarchy module ticked, it won;t work correctly as it is waiting for something on the child sheet, so you will get 0V. As it is wired now, you will get -10.5V as it is not configured correctly. Make sure your real life circuit actually has ±12V supply. If pin 4 is connected to GND and it is wired up as shown, then you will be getting close to 0V

Comment: @MCG My circuit has +- 12V supply. I get 24 volts, divide it with a step-down module and obtain 12 volts. I use 24v as +12v, 12v as ground and 0 as -12v. Both my real life and simulation circuit are not working. Not even in comparator config. In given setup pin 4 is connected to -12, 7 is connected to +12.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. As you've shown it, you should be getting something like -10 to -12 volts. Not +10 to +12.

If you had +12 on the output, the + input would be at about 1 volt, the - input at + 6 is greater than the +, so the output will go negative.

If both your simulation and circuit show 0 volts, I suggest that you are confused about your schematic. The most likely problem is that pin 4 is not connected to -12, it is connected to ground. In your physical circuit, measure both supplies. I doubt very much that you'll get +12 and -12.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to use TL071 to make a comparator, which didnt work.

To use an op-amp as a comparator,

- If you have a bipolar power supply (you do), and
- If you want to compare a signal to ground (OV) (I think you do)

You may use this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBaXNP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output, if you use a rail-to-rail op-amp, looks like this:

[image]

If you do not use a rail-to-rail op-amp, the voltage swing will be less. You can simulate this circuit yourself using the link provided.

Note that there is no feedback loop at all. A vanilla comparator should not have a feedback loop.

- If you have a bipolar supply, and
- If you want to compare a signal to some other fixed voltage

You may use a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsL7Mc.png)</sup>

In this circuit, the resistor values provide a reference voltage of 4V. The sine wave input is +/- 8V, and the output looks like this:

[image]

Once again, feedback is not used.

Comment: I have been working on this for 5 days, and it doesnt work. I always get this weird waveform I added to the actual question.

Comment: The schematic does not match the description you give of your physical test. Please add a schematic that corresponds to the waveform in your physical test. Are you still using any resistors? What is the frequency in your test? You may have reached maximum slew rate.

Comment: Also, what is the op-amp driving? And, how are you probing the result? Unless your input is really tiny, or your frequency too high, the output, if correctly wired, should be near +/- 10V.

Comment: Op-amp is driving a sine wave I created with an oscillator and amplified with another op-amp. Mainly a sine wave with 2V peak. Frequency is around 16kHz. I will post the whole schematic when I get home, sorry.

Comment: Op-amp is _driven_ by a sine wave from an amplifier. What is it _driving_? What is the output of the op-amp connected to? Also, how are you connecting the op-amp output to the oscilloscope?

Comment: Oh I get it I am sorry. Op-amp drives nothing, this is for a function generator I am trying to make. In these tests op-amp drives nothing. I am connecting the ground of the probe to the ground (not -12V, to the 0V) and probe itself to the output of the op-amp.

Comment: A 741 opamp design is 53 years old and has trouble with high output levels above 9kHz. The 741 or TL071 opamp will get hot if its load to ground is less than 2k ohms. Is the input of your oscilloscope only 50 ohms?

Comment: I loaded the tl017 with 100k ohms, it still gets hot. My probe has 1m resistance as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The TL071 and TL081 have Jfet inputs which cause the problem called Phase Inversion where the output suddenly goes as high as it can if an input voltage becomes within 4V to the negative power supply voltage.

Your sinewave is probably 0.7V peak and the first TL071 opamp with a gain of 16 times produces a clipping waveform with plus and minus 11.2V peaks which is too much negative input voltage for the second TL071 and third TL071 opamps.

Which opamp gets hot?? The loads are not shown on your schematic. The load on an opamp must be 2k ohms or higher.

[image: phase inversion]

Comment: Oh I didnt know that there should be a 2k load on an op-amp thank you. When I run tests, I attach no loads to the first TL071 which is why I think it gets hot. About this phase inversion, what should I do? Should I just replace TL071? I chose it because it has high slew rate. Any other substitudes in mind?

Comment: first two op-amps are not TL071 they are UA741. It creates a sinewave just fine, not clipped. Around 7V peak.

Comment: On second thought, impedance of the probe is way more than 2k, shouldnt it be enough?

Comment: I added 100k ohm load to the output of the first TL071 and it still gets pretty hot that it burns my hand.

Comment: Your schematic shows TL071 opamps but now you said they are 741 opamps.

Comment: If you observe carefully, first two opAmps are 741 whole last two are 071

Comment: Oh wait I get the problem now. Check out the last schematic, thats what Im referring to.